# What is sort_order-ASC in Opencart's category controller file?

Tags: php, sql, opencart

Calling all opencart guru's. While trying to understand category page's sorting feature (sort by Name, Rating, Price etc). The line `p.sort_order-ASC` in `catalog/controller/product/category.php` baffles me. In SQL, a sort query is built similar to something like `ORDER BY table.field_name ASC/DESC` but I cannot deduce the logic of `p.sort_order-ASC`. Is it set as value to be passed to a javascript function?

```
$this->data['sorts'] = array();

        $this->data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_default'),
            'value' => 'p.sort_order-ASC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.sort_order&order=ASC' . $url)
        );
```

Answer (score 3):

OpenCart takes the value you have there and sorts it based on those, so it orders by `p.sort_order` (which is the `product` table's alias `p` and the `sort_order` field) followed by the way it is sorted which is `ASC` or ascending

Answer (score 0):

Actually the line

```
'value' => 'p.sort_order-ASC',
```

is used in the template file (e.g. `catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl`) for highlighting (selecting) the selected sorting type. In the mentioned controller the `sort` and `order` are obtained from the `GET` - concretely from the URL that is hit and is defined by this line:

```
'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.sort_order&order=ASC' . $url)
```

As You can see, the URL contains the `&sort` and `&order` parameters the necessary values are obtained from and pushed to the template.

In the template there is this condition:

```
    <?php foreach ($sorts as $sorts) { ?>
    <?php if ($sorts['value'] == $sort . '-' . $order) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
    <?php } else { ?>
```

so if `$sort . '-' . $order` obtained from the URL is the same as the sort's **value**, the `<option>` is selected.

Is it clearer now?